# Unique Periodic orbit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

So I have the following ODE:

$\ddot{x}-(1-x^{2}-\dot{x}^{2})\dot{x}+x=0$

Now I have converted this ODE to polar coordinates which resulted in the following:

$\dot{x}=rcos(\theta)$ and $x=rsin(\theta)$

I am trying to figure out what the unique period orbit $\gamma$ is as I want to find the flow on this orbit. However, I am not sure how to use this system of polar cooridnates to quantify the orbit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $x^2 + \dot{x}^2 = 1$ the ODE says $\ddot{x} + x = 0$, and a solution of this is $x = \cos(t+c)$ which does have $x^2 + \dot{x}^2 = 1$.

Comment: I see, so is x=cos(t+c) a uniue periodic orbit of the system with period $2\pi$?

Comment: Note that $\dfrac{d}{dt} (x^2 + \dot{x}^2) = 2 \dot{x}^2 (1 - x^2 - \dot{x}^2)$.  So $x^2 + \dot{x}^2$ increases when $x^2 + \dot{x}^2 < 1$ and decreases when $> 1$.  The circle $x^2 + \dot{x}^2 = 1$ is the only periodic orbit (other than the fixed point $(0,0)$).